# Arrays and ArrayLists - Pros and Cons

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In Java, there are Arrays and ArrayLists.

```
// Creation of Array of length 3
Object[] array = new Object[3];

// Creation of ArrayList
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

From what I have found out, there are certain differences between Arrays and ArrayLists. For example, one can easily add an entry into an ArrayList, but not with an array.

Another difference I have found is that an ArrayList cannot contain primitives. **Why does this matter**, because I can easily cast int to an Integer object?

```
int[] array = {1,2,3}; // Can't add another entry.

ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(1);
arrayList.add(2);
arrayList.add(3);

arrayList.add(4); // Dynamic in size
```

From what I've googled, there are many benefits to using ArrayLists instead of normal Arrays, but **what are the cons of ArrayLists and in what scenarios should one use an Array over an ArrayList?** Also, if there are no cons of using ArrayLists, **why didn't the Java developers replace arrays with ArrayLists?**

Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, `ArrayList` uses an array behind the scenes for you, and creates a new array when the array is at its limit. I have to use an array when communicating with JNI e.g. reading data from C/C++ libraries.

Comment: Please note that in earlier versions of Java, you couldn't say `ArrayList<String>` (or `<Integer>` or any other type).  You could only say `ArrayList`, which doesn't provide any type safety.

Comment: All elements of an `ArrayList` need to be reference types. Otherwise an `ArrayList<Integer>` could have primitives, and it wouldn't know whether it contained an address or a literal.

Comment: The main trade off is speed. Though probably not obvious except for large collections, an `Array` will be faster than an `ArrayList` since it does not need to manage the addition/removal of objects "behind the scenes" as pointed out by @LuiggiMendoza.

Comment: @Rarw So most of the time the difference in the speed between using an `Array` and an `ArrayList` is negligible?

Comment: @Rarw I won't say that speed is that much of a concern here. If you don't know how many items you want to fetch, then you should not use an array to begin with and if you use `ArrayList` it means you're willing to accept the performance hit when the inner array has to grow. If it's about access time, you just have few more calls in the stacktrace since using `ArrayList` you have to use the `get(int index)` method that, after all, just does `return array[index];` (after checking for upper and lower bounds) which, if using a regular JVM, doesn't cost that much.

Comment: I would use arrays rather than `ArrayList` for three reasons: 1) Primitive arrays, for example when copying the content of a file, where you will use `byte[]` (not `Byte[]` nor `List<Byte>`). 2) Access to libraries written in other programming languages through JNI e.g. access to dlls written in C or C++. 3) Writing a critical memory footprint application e.g. software for a pacemaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my mind the major advantages of using an `ArrayList` over a primitive array are its unconfined size, its API methods and from Java 1.5, its use of generics. An `ArrayList` is backed by a primitive array, so technically speaking if you wanted to maintain a whole lot code yourself, you *could* use a primitive array but why would you want to do that, when what you're probably looking for is provided out of the box? Furthermore, since `ArrayList` is a `Collection`, amongst other things (`List` etc.), it opens you up to a wealth of library functions, both native and third party.

The disadvantage of using an `ArrayList` when all you need is a primitive array (E.G. you want a fixed length data structure, don't require generics and don't need any API functionality) is that it's more expensive to create and maintain.